# How to sync folder with files on disk?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've got a folder in my project called "Data". I want all the files in it to have the property `Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer`. Problem is every time I copy files into this directory via explorer, I have to remember to then copy the files into my actual project as well and then change the properties again.

Is there a way to keep this folder sync'd/up to date in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the files to your solution.  VS will manage files in the solution, but there's no simple or recommended way of managing a *general* list of files in a folder.